# Not valid kernel header path during vmware tools installation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vmware-tools

During the vmware tools instalation on a CentOS 7 MV (running on ESXi 5.5, tools version VMwareTools-8.6.5-621624) I have the next problem:

```
Searching for a valid kernel header path...
The path "" is not a valid path to the 3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64 kernel
headers.
Would you like to change it? [yes]
```

I know that this problems is common. Normaly I solve it executing:

```
yum install kernel-headers
yum install kernel-devel

export kernel_headers=`ls -hd /usr/src/kernels/3*`

sudo ln -s ${kernel_headers}/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h ${kernel_headers}/include/linux/version.h
```

But this time, the error persist. The target MV is a critical mail server, and I can't reboot it. Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing vmware tools: not recognizing path to 3.8.0-19-generic kernel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805697/installing-vmware-tools-not-recognizing-path-to-3-8-0-19-generic-kernel-files), [What is the path to the kernel headers so I can install vmware?](https://askubuntu.com/q/40979), [<empty path> is not a valid path to the kernel headers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230857/56041), [Empty kernel directory but kernel-headers are installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215694/56041), etc.

Comment: First times that I saw the error I used the links that you share for solve the problem. But this time it's not working.